# Is there a way to fetch the suiteName and testName defined at @Test annotation in TestNG?

Tags: testng

@Test(dataProvider = "data", dataProviderClass = TestDataProvider.class, groups = {"Smoke", "Function"}, priority = 1, description = "Some Description", enabled = true, suiteName = "abc", testName = "def")

I tried ITestNGMethod method, but couldn't find anything that could get the suiteName/testName defined in @Test Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach with `IAnnotationTransformer` like shown below:

```java
public class NewTest implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Test(testName = "def", suiteName = "abc")
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        System.out.println(annotation.getTestName());
        System.out.println(annotation.getSuiteName());
        IAnnotationTransformer.super.transform(annotation, testClass, testConstructor, testMethod);
    }
}
```

The only downside is that you cannot register the listener of this type using annotation so you'll have to either register it using `-listener` option of command line or define it in `testng.xml` file.